# What is meant by inertia group of (completion) of number field?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

I am reading the following [paper on homotopy obstruction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0164.pdf) and am confused by the following notation for number fields:

On page 25, it defines

> Let $K$ be a number field, $K_v$ a cmpletion of $K$.
>
> - $\Gamma_K$ is absolute galois group of $K$.
> - $I_v <\Gamma_v < \Gamma_K$ be the decomposition group and inertia
>   groups, and $\Gamma^{un}_v$ the unramified Galois group.

Firstly, I suppose $v$ is a choice of place here.

**Question: What is the definition of $I_v, \Gamma_v$?**

---

The definition of decomposition group and inertia group I am using are from this [notes, page 5 and 16 respectively.](https://alex-youcis.github.io/localglobalgalois.pdf)  I am confused by what, say,

> the inertia group $I_v$ of $K_v$

is. If I follow the notes by Youcis, it is the kenel of a map $Gal(L/W) \rightarrow Gal(k_l/k_W)$, where $W$ is a local field, and $L$ is a Galois extension. Supposing our choice of $W$ is $K_v$, what is the choice of $L$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $O_K$ corresponding to $v$, $O_{K_v}=\varprojlim O_K/\mathfrak{p}^n$,$K_v=O_{K_v}[\pi_{K_v}^{-1}]$

$L= \overline{K_v}$ (into which $\overline{K}$ is dense whatever embedding you choose), $k_l=O_{\overline{K_v}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\overline{K_v}}$ (an algebraic closure of $k_w$),$k_w=O_{K_v}/(\pi_{K_v})$. Then $I_v=\ker(Gal(L/W) \rightarrow Gal(k_l/k_W))$ and $\Gamma_v = Gal(L/W) =D_\mathfrak{P}$ where $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal of $O_{\overline{K}}$ above $v$ and $D_\mathfrak{P}$ is the subgroup of $Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ which is continuous for (the valuation corresponding to) $\mathfrak{P}$.

Comment: So it seems that we are taking $W=K_v$?

Comment: So what confuses me is if  $W=K_v$, why is  $Gal(L/W)$ identified with $D_{\mathfrak{P}}$ Is there a reference where I can read more about what's happening?

Comment: Yes, so what I don't see is the map $\Gamma_v \rightarrow Gal(\bar{K}/K)$

Comment: By density of $\overline{K}$ we have a natural injection $Gal(\bar{K}_v/K_v) \rightarrow Gal(\bar{K}/K)$ (restricting $\sigma$ to $\overline{K}$). The LHS is the subgroup of elements of the RHS that are continuous for $v$ (by density such a continuous automorphism on $\overline{K}$ extends to $\overline{K}_v$)

Comment: in retrospect, is t clear why 
1. $\bar{K}$ is dense in $\overline{K_v}$
2. if $\overline{K_v}$ s complete ?

Comment: Also, in which case, wouldn't $D_{\mathfrak P}$ open?

Comment: now reading this post again, what happens when $v$ is an infinite place? Your argument seems to refer to the finite case?